# Step response given impulse response $h = e^{-|t|}$

Tags: homework, step-response

I was given the above homework problem and I know how the step response is achieved, but I'm not sure how to set up the integrals in order to evaluate the problem. I've attached my work, but it is wrong because I keep getting the wrong answer. The solution is given as

$$S(t) = u(-t)e^t + u(t)(2-e^{-t})$$

*Note: We have not yet covered laplace transform. In my class, we are expressing the step response as running sums/integrals of the impulse response.[image]

Comment: Given what is mentioned in your question, can you please add a **representative** plot of the step function and a plot of the given $h$?

Comment: Hi A_A, the step function is 1 for all t equal to or less than 0, and the plot is rudimentary. The plot of the step function or impulse response h is not given, as this is a completely analytical problem.

Comment: edit:  step function is 1 when t is equal to or greater than 0.

Comment: No worries. The way the question was phrased initially, I thought it might helped if you simply sketched what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** In your work you implicitly assume that $t\ge 0$, so your solution is (probably) correct for $t\ge 0$, but you must also consider the case $t<0$.

Comment: hmmm but I thought I accounted for negative t when I'm integrating from -inf to 0?

Comment: @LeeJordan: No, you have to integrate from $-\infty$ to $t$, and if $t <0$ that interval does not include the value zero.

Comment: OOOOH thank you, Matt! I will do this as soon as I get home. I can just multiply the result of the integral by u(-t) afterwards and that will take care of the case that t>0. thank you so much!